# Visit 2.6.2 requires python 2.6?

Tags: python, visualization

I installed visit 2.6.2 (https://wci.llnl.gov/codes/visit/home.html) and when I try to run it it gives me the following error:

```
"error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.6.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
```

I have python 2.7.3 up and running.

Comment: I peeked into that web site and saw instructions how to build from source. Try that.

Comment: It looks like you're using a precompiled binary, and your host has a newer version of Python than Visit was compiled with.  You should probably consider building from source, or installing Python 2.6, if your distro supports it.

Comment: Installed python 2.6, solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you've got python2.6 installed, then this looks like you need to set up your `ldconfig` (assuming you're on *nix). Add a line to `/etc/ldconfig` that lists the directory that `libpython2.6.so.1.0` is installed in, and then run `ldconfig`:

```
# We can try to find libpython2.6.so...
find / -name libpython2.6*

# Suppose it's in /usr/local/lib, add that line to /etc/ldconfig
echo '/usr/local/lib' | sudo tee -a /etc/ldconfig

# Update ldconfig, and you should be golden!
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: still doesn't work, the full error is this: "/usr/local/visit/bin/../current/linux-x86_64/bin/python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.6.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: Can you give the output from `find / -name libpython2.6*`? It also might be an issue of `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Answer (score 0):

You should add this:

```
/----/VisIt/current/linux-x86_64/lib
```

to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` enviroment variable, then Visit will be OK.